# psql syntax error at or near "+"

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to use arithmetic calculation:

```
\set startSmallOffset 1000000
\set traineeNext :startSmallOffset+2000

ALTER SEQUENCE record_trainee_id_seq RESTART WITH :traineeNext
```

The error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
>   LINE 1: ALTER SEQUENCE record_trainee_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000000+2000...

It works if I remove '+2000'

Appreciate any advice

Comment: The value for the `restart with` can't be an expression - it must be a constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html) `setval()` with an expression:

```
\set startSmallOffset 1000000
\set traineeNext :startSmallOffset+2000

select setval('record_trainee_id_seq', :traineeNext);
```